# Setting the position of a tab Scrollbar when updaing the VerticalScroll Value

Tags: .net-4.0, c#-4.0, location, scrollbar, position

I am updating a number of controls dynamically on a tabpage within a c# application. The tab page has autoscroll enabled. As you may be aware, when the user has scrolled down it sets the location x=0,y=0 to be at the current x=0,y=0.

so:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| X                             |---|    X is now 0,0 in terms of setting locations.
|                               | - |
|                               |---|
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
|                               |   |  
|                               |   |      
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
|             TEXT              |   |
|                               |   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

AND

```
+-----------------------------------+
| X                             |   |    X is now 0,0 in terms of setting locations.
|             TEXT              |   |
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
|                               |---|
|                               | - |  
|                               |---|      
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Therefore I have to save the VerticalScroll.Value, set it to 0, update the controls and then set the VerticalScroll.Value back to the original value.

This works to a degree, the position of the tab form is correct, however the scrollbar doesn't update, so it looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|                               |---|  
|             TEXT              | - |
|                               |---|
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
|                               |   |  
|                               |   |      
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
|                               |   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Is there any easy way to update the position of the scrollbar?

If I leave it as it is, when the user clicks on the scrollbar again it moves the position back to the top of the tab form. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition.aspx